# The structure of exploding buckminsterfullerene-nitrous oxide compounds

Tags: carbon-allotropes, nitro-compounds

Recently, looking into structures of buckminsterfullerenes, I have found several articles claiming that attaching 12, or “several” nitrous oxide molecules to the buckminsterfullerene will cause it to degrade exothermically, heating the surroundings to several thousand degrees in “picoseconds”. The degradation would produce more nitrous oxide, further carrying on the reaction.

As I remember, they didn’t have any cited sources, or give any creditable evidence, or give the structure of the nitrous oxide-buckminsterfullerene compound. So I’m wondering, **where are the NOs attached on the C60?**, and **what is the structure of this compound?**(preferably a diagram?)

I searched it on many places, but to no avail.

Thanks,
Max0815

Comment: Downvoters, mind I ask you why?

Comment: NOs are _not yet attached_ to C60, so it is a little early to ask "where".

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don’t understand. Could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: What's to understand? In effect, you are asking what is the height of the spire on a particular building in a land far away. We know very little of that land. We are not even quite sure that the said building _exists_, let alone whether it has a spire.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So the buckybomb has not been built yet you mean?

Comment: Well, there were some reports of making something of which we don't even know the exact composition, much less the structure. In terms of my analogy, some people have been to that land and claim to have seen the building, but the solid evidence (like a photo) is yet to come. Then again, pretty much all organics with enough nitro groups is explosive, so that's hardly exciting news anyway.

Comment: Just look for some of the most common functionalization of fullerene, it can be addition and so on. But then look at the last comment of Ivan Neretin. "So what? " is appropriate out of a context.

Comment: @IvanNeretin https://phys.org/news/2015-03-buckyballs-bucky-bombs.html which says “To build the miniature explosives, Prezhdo and his colleagues attached 12 nitrous oxide molecules to a single Bucky-Ball and then heated it. Within picoseconds, the Bucky-Ball disintegrated—increasing temperature by thousands of degrees in a controlled explosion.

The source of the explosion's power is the breaking of powerful carbon bonds, which snap apart to bond with oxygen from the nitrous oxide, resulting in the creation of carbon dioxide, Prezhdo said.”